# How can I break into event listeners in Python (another thread)?

Tags: python, multithreading, debugging, pynput

I have this code:

```
from pynput import keyboard
import time

# The key combination to check
COMBINATIONS = []

# The currently active modifiers
current = set()
current_2 = set()

def main():
    def execute():
        print (f"Hotkeys {current} pressed")

    def on_press(key):
        if hasattr(key, 'vk'):
            current.add(key.vk)
            current_2.add(key)
        else:
            current.add(key.value.vk)
            current_2.add(key.name)



    def on_release(key):
        if len(COMBINATIONS) != 1:
            COMBINATIONS.append(set(current))
            COMBINATIONS.append(set(current_2))
            current.clear()
            current_2.clear()
        return False


    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

I would like to know what happens in e.g. on_press() using the PyCharm debugger. However, as soon as main executes, the debugger simply halts and I cannot break into anything. This happens whenever I deal with events in Python (which in this case are multiple threads). How could I break into those threads and functions?

I am using PyCharm community version (the newest one afaik).

Tried different settings in PyCharm. Tried stepping to various breakpoints and functions. Nothing works.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3oe4.png)

Comment: did you try putting the breakpoint inside the `on_press` function ?

Comment: How is `main` called?

Comment: Main is called simply by running the python console in debug mode. @AhmedAEK yes, l'll add a screenshot in the original post.